# Teamcity REST API get changes commit graph

Tags: git, teamcity

Is there a way to get information of the changes graph so I can reconstruct the teamcity changes interface in another application.

On the teamcity changes screen I can see:

[image]

Currently I'm getting all the changes using the `http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(id:19930)&fields=count,change:(version,username,date,href,comment,files),changegraph`

I can see the information in the `vcs_changes_graph` table but I'd rather not have to query the database directry